# Does Caliburn Micro work with HandyControl elements? (ex: PasswordBox)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, passwordbox

I have a HandyControl passwordbox and trying to use Caliburn Micro to capture password change but the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` is not firing on the password box...any ideas?

XAML

```xml
<hc:PasswordBox Margin="10" 
                Name="Password"  
                ShowClearButton="True" 
                ShowEyeButton="true" 
                hc:InfoElement.Placeholder="Password" 
                Height="34" 
                Width="174"/>
```

--UPDATE--
So i found the solution. HandyControl Passwordbox has isSafeEnabled property that needs to be set to true, then bind to UnsafePassword.

it will look like this:

```
<hc:PasswordBox Margin="10" 
                Name="Password"  
                ShowClearButton="True" 
                ShowEyeButton="true"
                IsSafeEnabled="true"
                UnSafePassword="{Binding Path=Password}"
                hc:InfoElement.Placeholder="Password" 
                Height="34" 
                Width="174"/>
```

Comment: I can see no binding for the control at all - how should they know they had to talk to each other?

Comment: i thought Caliburn Micro uses naming conventions to bind things together...it works perfectly if i use System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox instead of HandyControl one.

Comment: How is Caliburn supposed to know which property of the custom `hc:PasswordBox` to bind to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Caliburn Micro work with HandyControl elements? (ex: PasswordBox)?

Apparently not out of the box, which makes perfect sense since Caliburn.Micro cannot be supposed to know which target property of a custom control to bind to.

Try to define a binding to the `UnsafePassword` property explicitly.

Comment: yes i tried that but it doesnt work because there is no Dependency property for security reasons. My problem is that HandyControl PasswordBox doesnt have PasswordChanged event...so im just wondering if anyone faced this issue using HandyControl and Caliburn Micro

Comment: If there is no dependency property you need a work around similar to the one Caliburn.Micro has for the built-in `PasswordBox` control.

Comment: i figured it out. There is UnsafePassword property in the hc:PasswordBox that allows to bind to. I was missing IsSafeEnabled in the PasswordBox set to True :) Thanks for all the help

Comment: So then you should explicitly bind to `UnsafePassword` as per my answer.

Comment: yeah @mm8 just missed IsSafeEnabled="true" property :)